# v-for render dynamically with key passed via props vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dynamic

I want to make a component, select component, and make it as reusable as possible.

I added the props option that pass an array of object and I can retrieve the data, but the problem is in the result.

I want to add a props that pass the key of the object (make it a variable so if I use another array of object that has not the same key it still work) that I want to show in the select component
for example:

```
user : [
    {
      name : "Jo",
      contact : "021"
    },
    {
      name : "Bo",
      contact : "022"
    }
]
```

and you can choose to show either the name or the contact but it doesn't work , here is my code , can you help me please ?

here is the component file

```
<template>
<div>
<div>Selected : </div>
    <select class="form-select">
        <option v-for="(option,i) in options" :key="i">
            {{ option.variable }}
        </option>
    </select>
  </div>
 </template>
```

the script of the component

```
<script>
export default {
props: {
    label : {
        type : String,
        default : "",
    },
    options : {
        type : Array,
        default : () => [],
    },
    variable : {
        type : String,
        default : "",
    },
    selected : {
        type : Object,
        default : {}
    }
},
data () {
    return{
        vari : this.variable //here i tried to get the props and use it at the top but same 
 result
    }
   }
  }
 </script>
```

and here is where i call it

```
<template>
<div class="container">
<div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 class="text-left">Transaction</h2>
        <div>
            <base-select :options="proprietaires" :variable="nom"></base-select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Error message, not rendering, etc

Comment: it doesn't show any result when i put the variable at work , but if i do it statically it work

Comment: Does the variable `nom` exists in your parent component? You're binding it to your `variable` prop. Maybe it should be a string directly like `variable="name"` without the double colon `:`?

Comment: yes , the problem was the way i passed the props , instead of string i sent a variable

Answer (score 2):

Use bracket instead dot notation `option[variable]` or `option[vari]`:

```js
Vue.component('baseSelect', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>Selected : </div>
      <select class="form-select">
          <option v-for="(option,i) in options" :key="i">
              {{ option[variable] }}
          </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    label : {
        type : String,
        default : "",
    },
    options : {
        type : Array,
        default : () => [],
    },
    variable : {
        type : String,
        default : "",
    },
    selected : {
        type : Object,
        default : () => {}
    }
  },
  data () {
    return{
      vari : this.variable 
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      proprietaires: [{name : "Jo", contact : "021"}, {name : "Bo", contact : "022"}],
      nom: 'name'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2 class="text-left">Transaction</h2>
      <div>
        <base-select :options="proprietaires" :variable="nom"></base-select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i already tried it but it doesn't show , the array is there but, i think the app doesn't see the "variable", for the final rendering

Comment: @Dewei hey mate, did you check the snippet ?

Comment: it is finally working, this anwser helped too , the one below was the last thing needed to make it work

Comment: already there , thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

1. To access an object dynamically, you have to use the brackets notation: `myObject[myDynamicKey]`. Otherwise you'll try to access a key called `variable` in your object, which doesn't exists.
2. When you pass your `variable` prop, you use dynamic binding `:variable="nom"` which tries to access a variable called `nom`. I guess it doesn't exists, you should use simple binding (i.e. without the double colon `:` to pass in a string value)

```html
<!-- BaseSelect.vue uses dynamic key `variable` -->
<option v-for="(option,i) in options" :key="i">
   {{ option[variable] }}
</option>
```

```html
<!-- String binding -->
<base-select :options="proprietaires" variable="name"></base-select>

// or
<template>
  <!-- Variable binding -->
  <base-select :options="proprietaires" :variable="nom"></base-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      nom: 'name',
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: yes it is working , thank you so much , i was struggling and how you explained it is very clear